# Receiving UDP packets in android

Tags: android, udp

I am able to perform UDP broadcast in android. The client is expected to send its IP address. If there are 3 to 4 clients running on the same network, I am receiving the reply of only one client. 
I want to receive replies from all the clients. Here is my broadcaster code which even receives data sent from clients.

```
public class Scan4Activity extends Activity {
TextView tv;
int i=-1;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("ggrerrrrrrrggg", "hhaqaaaaaaaaaaahhhhhhh");
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //String[] b=;
    try {
        Log.i("ggggg", "hhhhhhhhh");
        String modifiedSentence="received!!!:)";
            main(null);
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), modifiedSentence, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         System.out.println("FROM SERVER:error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

   public void main(String args[]) throws Exception
   {
      DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
      InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255");
      byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];

      String sentence = "hello";//inFromUser.readLine();
      sendData = sentence.getBytes();
      DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 16789);
      clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
      while(true){
      byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
      DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
      clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
      String modifiedSentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());


      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), modifiedSentence, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      System.out.println("FROM SERVER:" + modifiedSentence);



     try{
      clientSocket.close();
     }
     catch(Exception e){

         System.err.println("Cannot Close the Socket" );
     }
   }
 }
```

So please can any one help?

Answer (score 1):

When you test this, do you test over a 2g/3g network, or do you test via wifi, since if you test using 2g/3g you will most likely not have static ip's on the handsets by rather some "local" ip only valid within the 2g/3g network and as soon as the udp package leaves the mobile operators network and goes out on internet it will look like its coming from the operators ip and thus the same for all the handsets.

Comment: No. I am not testing it on 2g/3g network but I am testing it on WIFI... I am broadcasting using 255.255.255.255..